# how to call specific procedures from one package using if else condition in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 3 procedures. I want to add that 3 procedures in one package and call that procedures depend on if else conditions inplsql.

Comment: Hi, Please check my answer

Comment: Hi, if it was what you want, please mark my answer as accepted

Answer (score 2):

here is sample code for your question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE
AS
   --You Can Comment below procedures if they are not needed out side of package and vice versa
   --PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_1 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2);

   --PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_2 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2);

   --PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_3 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2);*/

   PROCEDURE CALLER (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2, CONDITION_1 IN CHAR);
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACKAGE
AS
   PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_1 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PROCEDURE_1(' || PARAM_1 || ')');
   END;

   PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_2 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PROCEDURE_2(' || PARAM_1 || ')');
   END;

   PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_3 (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2)
   AS
   BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PROCEDURE_3(' || PARAM_1 || ')');
   END;

   PROCEDURE CALLER (PARAM_1 IN VARCHAR2, CONDITION_1 IN CHAR)
   AS
   BEGIN
      CASE (CONDITION_1)
         WHEN '1'
         THEN
            PROCEDURE_1 (PARAM_1);
         WHEN '2'
         THEN
            PROCEDURE_2 (PARAM_1);
         WHEN '3'
         THEN
            PROCEDURE_3 (PARAM_1);
         ELSE
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Unknown Condition: [' || CONDITION_1|| ']');
      END CASE;
   END;
END;

BEGIN
   MY_PACKAGE.CALLER ('Hello World!', '1');
   MY_PACKAGE.CALLER ('Hello World!', '2');
   MY_PACKAGE.CALLER ('Hello World!', '3');
   MY_PACKAGE.CALLER ('Hello World!', '4');
END;
```

**Output**:

```
PROCEDURE_1(HELLO WORLD!)
PROCEDURE_2(HELLO WORLD!)
PROCEDURE_3(HELLO WORLD!)
UNKNOWN CONDITION: [4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..! It helped me alot. As i am a new in this so i learned about it.